# Bypass static method in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, static-methods

I am using Mockito to write a JUnit Test Case and I am trying to bypass a static method invocation inside my test method. I am getting a `NullPointerException` while running the Test Case.

Is there any way of bypassing the above mentioned invocation without using `PowerMockito` or what fixes are needed in the below mentioned approach?

Below are the code snippets which will help you understand the problem:

**=>** This is my Code for which I want to write a JUnit Test Case using Mockito.

```
class MyClassToTest{
    public void methodToTest(){
        JsonObject obj = MyUtilClass.staticMethod(arg1);
    }
}
```

**=>** Below is the definition of the `MyUtilClass`:

```
class MyUtilClass{
    public static JsonObject staticMethod(JsonObject arg1){
        //use arg1 to populate return object 
        return jsonobject;
    }
}
```

**=>** Below is the snippet of how my current Test Class and Test Method looks for `MyClassToTest.methodToTest`

```
  class MyTestClass{
    public void test_methodToTest(){
        JsonObject dummy_jsonObject = new JsonObject().put("foo","foo");
        doReturn(dummy_jsonObject).when(MyUtilClass.staticMethod(any()));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you mock the ```arg1``` variable inside the ```MyTestClass``` test suite?

Comment: "*Is there any way of bypassing the above mentioned invocation without using `PowerMockito` or what fixes are needed in the below mentioned approach?*" - Since v3.4.0 [Mockito can mock static methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v3.4.0)

Comment: @marcin.programuje, no, ```arg1``` cannot be mocked as it is a huge Json payload.

Comment: If you can change the tested code, the simplest solution would be to move the call of the static method into an own method (e.g. with package scope) and simply stub this method.

Comment: @Coder3108 _huge_ has not really precise meaning. Maybe you should try to mock it instead of mocking static method.

Comment: this question makes no sense in a way. Mockito _can_ mock static methods - what is the problem?

Comment: @Eugene, the problem isn't exactly whether Mockito can mock static methods, it is the null pointer exception that is arising when trying to bypass the method. The code snippets are given above.

Comment: @Coder3108 are we suppose to guess where that happens? Provide a simple sample/project we can run and see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mock your `staticMethod` from `MyUtilClass` with Mockito (version 3.4.0 or greater required), the stubbing looks like the following (I assume you use a Java version > 9):

```
@Test
void shouldMockStatic() {
  JsonObject dummy_jsonObject = new JsonObject().put("foo","foo");
  try (MockedStatic<MyUtilsClass> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(MyUtilsClass.class)) {
    mockedStatic.when(() -> MyUtilsClass.staticMethod(anyString()).thenReturn(dummy_jsonObject);

    // now invoke your class under test
  }
}
```

You can find further information and examples of this feature of Mockito [here](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/).